# Let 4 linearly dependent vectors such that any 3 of them is independence

Tags: vector-spaces

Kinda stuck at this question and confused.

Let 4 Linearly dependent vectors exist in the F field.            Such that any 3 of them are linearly independent.

Let the 4 vectors be {${u,v,w,x}$}.
Let L=Span{${u,u-2v,u+3v+w,w+x}$}.

Find the dimL.

In my opinion the dim is 3 but it’s a wild guess.

I found it with examples like (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,1). And because (1,1,1) is linearly dependent the vector is also dependent in L.

How can I know what is the dim of L without similar inputs - only by the definition of the span.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $u \in L$. Then since $u \in L$ and $u-2v \in L$ we also have $v \in L$ (we can write $v = \frac{1}{2}u - \frac{1}{2}(u-2v)$). Now since $u+3v+w \in L$, we conclude that $w \in L$ as well (since $w = (u+3v+w)-u-3v$). And so finally from the fact that $w+x \in L$ we have $x \in L$ (since $x = (w+x)-w$). Therefore $\text{span}(u,v,w,x) \subseteq L$.

Conversely, we also have $L \subseteq \text{span}(u,v,w,x)$ since the vectors used to define $L$ are all in $\text{span}(u,v,w,x)$.

Hence $L=\text{span}(u,v,w,x)$, so all that remains is to show that the dimension of $\text{span}(u,v,w,x)$ is $3$.

Comment: Got it , makes sense. Thank you very much!